# How do I fix my compareTo method for a set?

Tags: java, set

There are 128 football teams however, when I print out the size of the set...I only get 114. Can anyone help me fix my compareTo method to fix this error.I've even compared multiple fields but its not accommodating for this error.

This is the football class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Football implements Comparable<Football>
{
public String name;
public int wins,finalRecord14,finalRecord13,finalRecord12,finalRecord11,bowlVictories,bowlLosses,ConferenceChamps;
public Integer points;
public Football(String name,int wins,int finalRecord14,int finalRecord13,int finalRecord12,int finalRecord11,int bowlVictories,int bowlLosses,int ConferenceChamp,Integer points)
{
       this.name=name;
       this.wins=wins;
       this.finalRecord14=finalRecord14;
       this.finalRecord13=finalRecord13;
       this.finalRecord12=finalRecord12;
       this.finalRecord11=finalRecord11;
       this.bowlVictories=bowlVictories;
       this.bowlLosses=bowlLosses;
       this.ConferenceChamps=ConferenceChamp;
       this.points=points;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public int getWins()
{
    return wins;
}
public int getfinalRecord14()
{
    return finalRecord14;
}
public int getfinalRecord13()
{
    return finalRecord13;
}
public int getfinalRecord12()
{
    return finalRecord12;
}
public int getfinalRecord11()
{
    return finalRecord11;
}
public int getBowlVictories()
{
    return bowlVictories;
}
public int getBowlLosses()
{
    return bowlLosses;
}
public int getConferenceChamps()
{
    return ConferenceChamps;
}
public Integer getPoints()
{
    return points;
}
public int compareTo(Football o)
{
    if(getPoints()>o.getPoints())
        return 1;
    else if(getPoints()<o.getPoints())
        return -1;
    else
    {
        if(getWins()>o.getWins())
            return 1;
        else if(getWins()<o.getWins())
            return -1;
        else
        {
            if(getConferenceChamps()>o.getConferenceChamps())
                return 1;
            else if(getConferenceChamps()<getConferenceChamps())
                return -1;
            else
            {
                if(getBowlVictories()>o.getBowlVictories())
                    return 1;
                else if(getBowlVictories()<o.getBowlVictories())
                    return -1;
                else
                {
                    Random r=new Random();
                    int random=r.nextInt(2);
                    if(random==1)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the schedule class

```
     public class Schedule
     {
    public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("Footballteams.txt"));

    Set<Football>teams=new TreeSet<Football>();
    for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
    {
        String team=sc.nextLine();
        Integer points=0;
        String[]a=team.split("\\|",9);
        String name=a[0];
        int wins=Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
        points+=wins;
        int finalRecord14=Integer.parseInt(a[2]);
        int finalRecord13=Integer.parseInt(a[3]);
        int finalRecord12=Integer.parseInt(a[4]);
        int finalRecord11=Integer.parseInt(a[5]);
        int bowlVictories=Integer.parseInt(a[6]);
        points=points+(bowlVictories*10);
        int bowlLosses=Integer.parseInt(a[7]);
        points=points-(bowlLosses*5);
        int ConferenceChamp=Integer.parseInt(a[8]);
        points=points+(ConferenceChamp*10);
        Football x=new Football(name,wins,finalRecord14,finalRecord13,finalRecord12,finalRecord11,bowlVictories,bowlLosses,ConferenceChamp,points);
        teams.add(x);


    }


    System.out.println(teams.size());








}
```

}

This is the football text file

```
Georgia Southern(Sun Belt)|9|0|0|0|0|0|0|1
Louisana-Lafayette(Sun Belt)|36|0|0|0|0|4|0|1
Appalachian State(Sun Belt)|7|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Texas State(Sun Belt)|17|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Arakansas State(Sun Belt)|35|0|0|0|0|2|2|3
South Alabama(Sun Belt)|14|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Louisanna-Monroe(Sun Belt)|22|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Troy(Sun Belt)|17|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
New Mexico State(Sun Belt)|9|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Idaho(Sun Belt)|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Georgia State(Sun Belt)|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Memphis(AAC)|19|0|0|0|25|1|0|1
Cincinnati(AAC)|38|25|0|0|0|2|2|3
Central Florida(AAC)|36|0|0|10|0|2|1|2
East Carolina(AAC)|31|0|0|0|0|1|2|0
Houston(AAC)|34|18|0|0|0|2|1|0
Temple(AAC)|21|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
South Florida(AAC)|14|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Tulane(AAC)|14|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Tulsa(AAC)|24|0|0|0|0|1|1|1
Southern Methodist(AAC)|21|0|0|0|0|2|0|0
Connecticut|15|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Florida State(ACC)|48|23|10|1|5|3|1|3
Clemson(ACC)|42|22|11|8|15|3|1|1
Louisville(ACC)|39|0|13|15|24|2|2|1
Boston College(ACC)|20|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
North Carolina State(ACC)|26|0|0|0|0|2|1|0
Syracuse(ACC)|23|0|0|0|0|2|0|1
Wake Forest(ACC)|18|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Georgia Tech(ACC)|33|0|0|0|8|2|2|0
Duke(ACC)|28|0|0|23|0|0|2|0
North Carolina(ACC)|28|0|0|0|0|1|2|0
Pittsburgh(ACC)|25|0|0|0|0|1|3|0
Miami(ACC)|28|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Virginia Tech(ACC)|33|21|0|0|0|2|2|0
Virginia(ACC)|19|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Baylor(XII)|40|13|0|13|7|2|2|2
Texas Christian(XII)|44|14|0|0|3|2|1|2
Kansas State(XII)|38|15|12|0|18|0|3|1
Oklahoma(XII)|39|16|15|6|0|2|2|1
Texas(XII)|31|0|19|0|0|2|2|0
West Virginia(XII)|28|17|0|0|0|1|2|1
Oklahoma State(XII)|37|3|0|17|0|3|1|1
Texas Tech(XII)|25|0|0|0|0|2|0|0
Kansas(XII)|9|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Iowa State(XII)|17|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Ohio State(B1G)|44|0|3|12|1|2|2|1
Michigan State(B1G)|42|11|0|3|5|4|0|1
Maryland(B1G)|20|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Rutgers(B1G)|32|0|0|0|0|2|2|0
Michigan(B1G)|31|12|24|0|0|1|2|0
Penn State(B1G)|31|0|0|0|0|1|1|0
Indiana(B1G)|14|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Wisconsin(B1G)|39|10|0|22|13|1|3|2
Minnesota(B1G)|25|0|0|0|0|0|3|0
Nebraska(B1G)|37|24|25|0|0|1|3|0
Iowa(B1G)|26|0|0|0|0|0|3|0
Illinois(B1G)|19|0|0|0|0|1|1|0
Northwestern(B1G)|26|0|17|0|0|1|1|0
Purdue(B1G)|17|0|0|0|0|1|1|0
Marshall(CUSA)|35|0|0|0|23|3|0|1
Middle Tennessee(CUSA)|24|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Western Kentucky(CUSA)|30|0|0|0|0|1|1|0
Alabama-Birmingham(CUSA)|14|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Old Dominion(CUSA)|6|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Florida-International(CUSA)|16|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Florida-Atlantic(CUSA)|13|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Louisanna Tech(CUSA)|30|0|0|0|0|1|1|1
Rice(CUSA)|29|0|0|0|0|2|1|1
Texas-El Paso(CUSA)|17|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Texas-San Antonio(CUSA)|19|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
North Texas(CUSA)|22|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
Southern Mississippi(CUSA)|16|20|0|0|0|1|0|1
Bowling Green(MAC)|31|0|0|0|0|1|2|1
Ohio(MAC)|32|0|0|0|0|2|1|0
Buffalo(MAC)|20|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Akron(MAC)|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Massachusetts(MAC)|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Miami(MAC)|10|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Kent State(MAC)|22|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Northern Illinois(MAC)|46|0|22|0|0|1|3|3
Toledo(MAC)|34|0|0|0|0|2|1|0
Western Michigan(MAC)|20|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Central Michigan(MAC)|23|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Ball State(MAC)|30|0|0|0|0|0|2|0
Eastern Michigan(MAC)|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Boise State(MWC)|43|8|18|0|16|3|0|2
Colorado State(MWC)|25|0|0|0|0|1|1|0
Utah State(MWC)|37|0|16|0|0|3|1|1
Air Force(MWC)|25|0|0|0|0|1|2|0
New Mexico(MWC)|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Wyoming(MWC)|21|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Fresno State(MWC)|30|0|0|0|0|0|3|2
San Diego State(MWC)|32|0|0|0|0|1|3|1
Nevada(MWC)|25|0|0|0|0|0|3|0
Hawaii(MWC)|14|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
San Jose State(MWC)|25|0|21|0|0|1|0|0
Nevada-Las Vegas(MWC)|13|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Oregon(PAC12)|48|4|2|9|2|4|1|2
Stanford(PAC12)|42|7|7|11|0|2|2|2
Washington(PAC12)|31|0|0|25|0|1|3|0
California(PAC12)|16|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Oregon State(PAC12)|24|0|20|0|0|1|1|0
Washington State(PAC12)|16|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
Arizona(PAC12)|30|0|0|0|19|2|1|0
California-Los Angeles(PAC12)|35|0|0|16|10|2|2|0
Arizona State(PAC12)|34|0|0|21|12|2|2|0
Southern California(PAC12)|36|6|0|19|20|2|1|0
Utah(PAC12)|27|0|0|0|21|2|0|0
Colorado(PAC12)|10|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Missouri(SEC)|36|0|0|5|14|3|0|0
Georgia(SEC)|40|19|5|0|9|2|1|0
Florida(SEC)|29|0|9|0|0|1|1|0
Tennessee(SEC)|22|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
South Carolina(SEC)|40|9|8|4|0|4|0|0
Kentucky(SEC)|14|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
Vanderbilt(SEC)|27|0|23|24|0|2|1|0
Alabama(SEC)|48|1|1|7|4|2|2|2
Mississippi State(SEC)|32|0|0|0|11|2|2|0
Mississippi(SEC)|26|0|0|0|17|2|1|0
Auburn(SEC)|31|0|0|2|22|1|2|1
Louisiana State(SEC)|41|2|14|14|0|1|3|1
Texas A&M(SEC)|35|0|5|18|0|4|0|0
Arkansas(SEC)|25|5|0|0|0|2|0|0
Notre Dame(IND)|37|0|4|20|0|2|2|0
Brigham Young(IND)|34|0|0|0|0|2|2|0
Navy(IND)|30|0|0|0|0|2|1|0
Army(IND)|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Answer (score 2):

But you are reading only 114 lines.

```
 for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
    {
        String team=sc.nextLine();
        Integer ...
```

and there are no multiple teams per line nor the code to parse. You could have made it dynamic instead of hard-coded to read 114 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to define a constant (e.g. MAX_TEAMS = 128) rather than using an integer literal. Then you can use that in your loops/comparisons.

In reference to the Schedule class for loop...

```
for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
```

Comment: but when I put the limit as 128 I get an out of bounds error

Comment: I just copied your code and changed 114 to 128 and got "128" from the System.out.println(teams.size());  Where are you seeing the out of bounds error?